# RecursiveIteratorIterator Blank Page

Tags: php, spl

I'm trying to use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://docs.php.net/class.recursiveiteratoriterator) and [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://docs.php.net/class.recursivedirectoryiterator).

I want get all file inside my `c:\` folder. But i don't know why i can't get the result but a blank page.

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('c:/' ));
foreach( $it as $file ) {
    $all[] = $file->getRealPath();
}
print_r($all);
```

but if i use this code, it's work

```
foreach( $it as $key=>$file )
{
    echo $key."=>".$file."\n";
}
```

Comment: When asking such kind of questions, always provide the output as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because PHPs `StdObj`-class cannot be used as an array because it's an associative array. This is wrong by the words but I cannot describe it better. The PHP object gets casted or something like that.

If `$data` is an object then this is required if you want to access `$value` as an object.

```
foreach($data as $property => $value){
    echo $value->r;
}
```

Edit: This is a good question btw, I've spent a couple of hours myself figuring this out.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely because your PHP interpreter does not have access to that folder.

Comment: But why it work if i use the second code, echo $key."=>".$file."\n";